# Get back UniqueID after persist JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, uniqueidentifier

I have a uniqueID of date + sequence in Oracle.  Example: 20130307-000021

My entity object uniqueID looks like this:

```
@Id
// @GeneratedValue
// @Basic(optional = false)
// @NotNull
// @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
@Column(name = "UNIQUE_ID")
private String uniqueId;
```

Anytime I use @GeneratedValue or it's variants I get a "sequence not found" or some other error.  I'm trying to get back the unique ID that is generated by the Oracle database after I persist an object.

```
      this.dbConn.persist(orderDetail);
      this.dbConn.flush();
      //this.dbConn.refresh(orderDetail);
      //OrderDetails od = new OrderDetails();
      //od =(OrderDetails)this.dbConn.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(orderDetail);
```

The above are some various things I've tried.  When I use refresh I get an error saying "entity" not found (I assume it is looking up the entity based on the pre-persisted uniqueID of null.  Is it possible to get back that auto-generated date+sequence number?  I'm able to persist and retrieve objects just fine by looking at the inserted object and copying the uniqueID directly but obviously that is useless.  Any help much appreciated and if you would like to see error messages etc just let me know.  I've searched around and I either see 'solutions' that appear to be what I am trying or one person said he used a "brute-force work-around" but did not describe what that meant.

Comment: It's a chicken and egg problem. If your ID is generated by a trigger (as I assume it is), you need another unique ID to be able to get the row that has just been inserted and get the trigger-generated ID from it. Why don't you generate the ID first, then assign it to your entity and persist it?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We wanted the database to generate the uniqueID and not the code.  Perhaps we can just have the database generate a sequence without that date stamp.  From examples I've read it would appear I can reference that sequence via the @generatedvalue(strategy = generationtype.sequence)?  Here is my possible trigger if I attempt just a plain sequence:

Comment: `if INSERTING then
      if :new.UNIQUE_ID is null then
         select ourSchema.USERS_seq.nextval
         into :new.UNIQUE_ID
         from DUAL;
      end if;
  End If;`

Comment: So would it be correct to specify in my entity: `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`
`@GeneratedValue(generator="my_seq")`
`@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq",sequenceName="USERS_seq", allocationSize=1)`
???

Comment: The above solved my issue I just didn't use the @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) and used the two underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may happen upon this.  I kept the database trigger and just used:

```
 @Id
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
 @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
 private String orderId;
```

I didn't need to use @GeneratedValue or any of its variants.